# How to create this html page for a simple dashboard?

Tags: javascript, html, css, d3.js

I have no experience with web design and I am trying desperately to create a simple web page that will contain a `D3.js` graph (a sweet framework to create graphs and dashboards) but I have a very big problem with positioning elements.

I am trying to have a page that I represented like this:
[image]

The graph data will be generated by a back-end process interacting with some ajax code.
I know it's simple but I have a real problem with positions, margins, padding etc.

What I tried so far is this:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
</html>


<head>
  <title>E-Commerce data - Interactive Map</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'interactive_map.css' %}?v=00001">
</head>

<body bgcolor="#170061">
    <div id="graph_div">
      // The graph will be here
    </div>
    <div id="pannel_div">
      // The buttons to controle the graph will be here
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

And a css file that look like this:

```
div#graph_div
    {
      border-radius: 2px;
      vertical-align: middle;
      position: relative;
      width: 40%;
      height: 80%;
      top: 20px;
      bottom: 20px;
      right: 180px;
      left: 20px;
      background-color: #ffffff;
    }

div#panel_div
    {
      border-radius: 2px;
      vertical-align: middle;
      position: relative;
      width: 40%;
      height: 80%;
      top: 20px;
      bottom: 180px;
      right: 20px;
      left: 20px;
      background-color: #ffffff;
    }
```

Clearly this won't work ( I know ). Can anybody help me with this? 
Thank you in advance

Comment: what exactly is the problem?

Comment: I couldn't position the different elements (mainely divs)

Comment: then `position:relative` is not what you want. http://www.barelyfitz.com/screencast/html-training/css/positioning/

Comment: Ah ok! I didn't think that it's so complicated to create a page as simple as this one

Comment: Can you please correct my code? Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an example of what you could start doing: https://jsfiddle.net/Le232kar/

CSS looks like this:

```
body, html {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    height:100%;
}

#topbar {
    width:100%;
    height:100px;
    background:grey;
    margin:0;
}

#graph_div {
    width:60%;
    height:100%;
    float:left;
    background:blue;
}
#panel_div { 
    width:40%;
    float:right;
    background:darkgrey;
    height:100%;
}
```

Good luck.